# Flutter Google Mobile Ads Mediation Does Not Read Installed Adapter

Tags: flutter, admob

I have installed mediation adapter under the Podfile and they were synchronise successfully. However, the status show that it was not installed. Here is my Podfile

```
  # list of adapters
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

Here is the debugging result from my flutter app

```
flutter: Adapter status for com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookMediationAdapter: <GADAdapterStatus: 0x60000391c340; state = Not Ready;No such adapter in the application.>
flutter: Adapter status for GADMobileAds: <GADAdapterStatus: 0x60000391c200; state = Ready>
```

The pod installation has already successful but the adapter cannot be detected. I have set bidding  and waterfall mediation under the Admob dashboard. Here is the plugin that I was trying to achieve

https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

Need help with detecting installed adapters